# How to display all validation error of regsitartion page at once in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have customized new user registration form using child theme concept. For this I override the form-login.php file.

> wp-content/pluings/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php

My new registration from is looks like this

[image]

Now i am validating the fields like this -

```
    function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
           $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( 'First name cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
           $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( 'Last name cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) && empty( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( 'Date of birth cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_email_error', __( 'Confirm email address cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    /** Below Code added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration  */

    if(isset($_POST['billing_email']))
    {
        if($_POST['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $_POST['billing_email'])
        {//$_POST['billing_email']  email filed in checkout page
            error_log("Confirm Email checkout page - " . $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $_POST['billing_email']);
            $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Check Out Error Confirm Email address does not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }

    if( isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        if ( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $_POST['email']  ) {
            //$_POST['eamil']  email filed in Myaccount regisration page
            error_log("Confirm Email registration page - " . $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $_POST['email']);
            $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Registration Error Confirm Email address does not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
    
    /** End of above Code -- added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration  */


    if ( isset( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) && empty( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_password_error', __( 'Confirm password cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    /** Below Code added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration  */

    if(isset($_POST['account_password'] ))
    {
        if ( $_POST['user_password_again']  != $_POST['account_password']  ) {
            //$_POST['account_password'] Default password filed in Checkout page
           $validation_errors->add( 'password_not_match_error', __( 'Checkout Error Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'] ))
    {
        if ( $_POST['user_password_again']  != $_POST['password']  ) {
            //$_POST['account_password'] Default password filed in Myaccount regstration page
           $validation_errors->add( 'password_not_match_error', __( 'Registration Error Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }

    /** End of above Code -- added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration */
   
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mobile_number_error', __( 'Mobile number cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if(!validate_mobile($_POST['billing_phone']))
    {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mobile_number_error', __( 'Mobile number entry is numerical only and cannot contain any spaces.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    /*
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && strlen($_POST['billing_phone']) < 5 ) {
        $validation_errors->add('billing_mobile_number_error', __('<strong>Phone number length should not be less than 5 digit</strong>', 'woocommerce'));
    }
    */
    
    return $validation_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
```

It is working fine. but it shows validation error one by one (image attached for reference).

[image]

**I want to display all validation error at once. Any advice**

**UPDATE**

I have also tried the hook *woocommerce_process_registration_errors* instead of *woocommerce_register_post*. if i uses the hook *woocommerce_process_registration_errors*  so the list is showing but default validations of function wc_create_new_customer() (located in wc-user-functions.php file) is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `woocommerce_process_registration_errors` filter hook. try the below code.

```
function custom_woocommerce_process_registration_errors( $validation_errors, $username, $password, $email ){

    if ( !isset( $_POST['email'] ) || $_POST['email'] == '' ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'email', __( 'Please enter email address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( !isset( $_POST['password'] ) || $_POST['password'] == '' ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'password', __( 'Please enter passwors.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    return $validation_errors;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 'custom_woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 10, 4 );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bhautik for your reply. I have tried this hook. When I apply this hook, validation error messages of  wc_create_new_customer() function (i think they are default by woocommerce ) are not showing. Only the messages (custom validations) of call back function are showing. Do I have to rewrite the whole validations?

Comment: Yes, you have to write validation as per your need.

Comment: Thanks Bhautik. It is working. I added all the validations of  wc_create_new_customer() function to my callback function.